# Displaying a string from MasterViewController to DetailViewController using prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitextview, segue

I have declared a string as a property in 
 MasterViewController.h

```
    @property (nonatomic , readwrite) NSString *theString;
```

Here is my prepareForSegue method

```
     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
   [[segue destinationViewController] setTheString:string];

  //UITextField *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
  //dest.theString = string;
}
```

}

DetailViewController.h 
i have created an outlet for the textView

```
    @interface APPDetailViewController : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

Now, What to code in implementation so i can display "theString" in MasterViewController to the textField in DetailViewController ?

Comment: You need a property in the destination view controller called theString, otherwise it won't understand the setTheString message. You probably need to cast [segue destinationViewController] also, so the compiler knows what class it is.

Comment: How do i typecast the [segue destinationViewController] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - there should be `theString` property inside `DetailViewController`. (Optional, see step 3 below)

2 - For the above code to compile and run, you must also cast `destinationViewController` to `DetailViewController`.

Like this:

```
DetailViewController * destVC = (DetailViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
```

3 -

```
destVC.theString = string;
```

Optionally, without `theString` inside `DetailViewController`, you could do it like:

```
destVC.textView.text = string;
```

Answer (score 1):

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *myString; //Do this
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];

        //Do this
        APPDetailViewController *myController = (APPDetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        myController.myString = string;
    }
}
```

Try this way.